# Mutate (dplyr) based on multiple conditions (time intervals)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, posixct, dplyr

I'm struggling with conditional merging of the 2 datasets I have.

The first one has the following structure

```
 ID   Trip number       Time start             Time Stop       
  1        1        2018-04-10 14:44:38   2018-04-10 14:44:38  
  1        2        2018-04-10 16:28:08   2018-04-10 16:46:17  
  2        1        2018-04-10 22:47:56   2018-04-10 23:26:24
```

The second one has this one

```
 ID   Status          Time             
  1       a        2018-04-10 14:44:38     
  1       b        2018-04-10 16:28:08     
  2       c        2018-04-10 22:47:56
```

I'm trying to create a new column for the first df1 what contains the min time for each ID found into the second df2 that lays at the interval between start and stop time for each trip of an ID. Also I added 900 sec for the interval to make it wider.

My code so far looks like

```
try <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, Trip.number)  %>%
  mutate(ifelse((df1$Time.Start - 900) >= df2$Time & (df1$Time.Stop + 900) <= df2$Time & df1$ID %in% df2$ID), df2$Time, 0)
```

End it gives me the warning (the length of two datasets are different)

> Evaluation error: argument "no" is missing, with no default.
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In `>=.default`(df1$Time.Start - 900, df2$Time) :
>       longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 
>       2: In `<=.default`(df1$Time.Start + 900, df2$Time) :
>       longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Time is converted to POSIXct

Reproducible example

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5),
             Trip.number = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,3), 
             Time.start = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-10 14:44:38", "2018-04-10 16:28:08", 
                                       "2018-04-10 17:31:54", "2018-04-10 13:29:33", 
                                       "2018-04-10 22:47:56", "2018-04-10 10:03:15", 
                                       "2018-04-10 18:00:23", "2018-04-10 19:56:04", 
                                       "2018-04-10 08:52:00", "2018-04-10 09:54:50", 
                                       "2018-04-10 14:51:04", "2018-04-10 18:34:01")),
             Time.stop = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-10 15:30:59","2018-04-10 16:46:17",
                                      "2018-04-10 18:03:36", "2018-04-10 13:52:35",
                                      "2018-04-10 23:26:24", "2018-04-10 10:39:23",
                                      "2018-04-10 18:03:37", "2018-04-10 20:29:13",
                                      "2018-04-10 09:05:08", "2018-04-10 10:31:54",
                                      "2018-04-10 15:00:41", "2018-04-10 19:04:10")))

df2 <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              Time =  as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-10 18:34:01",
                                   "2018-04-10 19:04:10",
                                   "2018-04-10 12:07:35",
                                   "2018-04-10 12:13:59",
                                   "2018-04-10 11:06:00",
                                   "2018-04-10 11:46:20",
                                   "2018-04-10 18:56:51",
                                   "2018-04-10 19:10:03",
                                   "2018-04-10 09:06:06",
                                   "2018-04-10 09:29:04",
                                   "2018-04-10 18:04:47",
                                   "2018-04-10 18:21:24")))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please use `()` to separate each expression

Comment: What expression? Didn't get it

Comment: operators have precedence, so if you don't compartmentalize it with braces, something different can happen

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, but the warning didn't change

Comment: Within the group_by, you are doing the full data comparison `df1$`,  Remove that part

Comment: I removed group_by(ID, Trip.number) and it's the same.

Comment: I didn't meant to remove those.  I am talking about `mutate(ifelse(Time.Start - 900` instead of `mutate(ifelse(df1$`

Comment: I also tried it before, no success

Answer (score 1):

Small sample data set would be useful, but I think you just need parenthesis around the operations

```
mutate(ifelse( (df1$Time.Start - 900) >= df2$Time & (df1$Time.Stop + 900) <= df2$Time & df1$ID %in% df2$ID), df2$Time, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks: I've added example to the question: it didn't help as I believe the problem is in the length of the datasets. Same Warning